# Serialize abstract class with SuperBuilder using Jackson

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, lombok, javabuilders

I have following classes:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent {
    private String parentA;
    private String parentB;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
public class ChildOne extends Parent{
    private String childOneA;
    private String childOneB;
}
```

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@SuperBuilder
public class ChildTwo extends Parent{
}
```

```
Map<Parent, List<String>> parent2Strs = new HashMap<>();
parent2Strs.put(ChildTwo.builder().parentA("A").parentB("B").build(), List.of("1", "2"));
parent2Strs.put(ChildTwo.builder().parentA("C").parentB("D").build(), List.of("1"));
```

When I call writeValueAsString() method on the parent2Str class, it doesn't print any attribute in parent class.

I tried to use @Jacksonized on the abstract class. But received error:

> error: Builders on abstract classes cannot be @Jacksonized (the builder would never be used).

How can I include the fields in Parent class when serialize the child class?

Comment: Your `ChildOne`/`ChildTwo` classes don't `extend Parent`. Is that a typo? Otherwise it's obvious why it doesn't work.

Comment: @JanRieke. Thx. It is a typo. Fixed

Comment: That works for me, all attributes from child and parent are serialized. Please add more code so we can see exactly how you create the instance and serialize it.

Comment: @JanRieke Thank you for checking. I also tested. Looks like when printing the individual Child object, it will show the attributes from parent class. But when printing the child in a map, it doesn't show any attribute from parent class. Update the description.

Comment: Your updated code does not compile, and it's also not clear what you mean by "when printing the child in a map". Please add exactly the code that causes the problem.

Comment: @JanRieke Thx for checking. My apology. Update the code. I was trying to say that when writeValueAsString() each Child Object in a Child Object List,  it does show all the attribute for each class. But when writeValueAsString() the whole Map. The ChildTwo object doesn't have any attribute. Hope I explained my problem clearly this time

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has nothing to do with Lombok, `@SuperBuilder`, or `@Jacksonized`.
Jackson simply serializes map keys using the `toString()` method, because keys in JSON cannot be structured, but must be plain strings.

If you use your POJOs as map values, everything works as expected (and would also work without `@SuperBuilder`).

`@Jacksonized` wouldn't have an effect anyway, because it only affects the deserialization, not the serialization.

Comment: Thx. Sounds like a limitation of Java Map? So is there a way to print out the parent2Strs keys including the parent fields?

Comment: That's not a limitation of Java Maps. It's just the definition of JSON: JSON keys must be strings. You can still change the `toString` method, e.g. by adding `@ToString(callSuper=true)` to your classes.